# When should 'Unknown' be used as -Encoding parameter?

Tags: powershell

I was thinking Unknown option is used for binary files concatenation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315299.aspx

> **Unknown**  The encoding type is unknown
>   or invalid. The data can be treated as
>   binary.

But `{Get-Content binary.dat -Encoding Unknown}` doesn't return byte array but string array.

```
PS > $a = Get-Content $PSHOME\WTRInstaller.ico -Encoding Unknown
PS > $b = Get-Content $PSHOME\WTRInstaller.ico -Encoding Byte

PS > $a[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

PS > $b[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Byte                                     System.ValueType
```

Even if I convert $a to byte array, it doesn't coincide with $b.

```
PS > [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($a)
PS > compare $c[0..10] $b[0..10]

                                                InputObject SideIndicator
                                                ----------- -------------
                                                         10 =>
                                                         32 <=
```

When should 'Unknown' be used?

Comment: jalf, thank you for your good editing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uknown is not something that is supplied, but rather something that is *returned*. System.Text.Encoding is not just for use by powershell. There are many areas in the BCL that accept or return the same enums. Some values are for return, others for supplying.

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks Oisin, that is to say, it seems that I shouldn't use Unknown for something of another to use it.

Comment: It's not `System.Text.Encoding`, though, the value used by `Get-Content` is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding`, which, I guess, sees rather limited use outside of PowerShell.